# jQuery does not work in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, laravel

I tried to use a web library, and now I use it locally (also NPM installed it), but the function on button click doesn't give me any response. The console log is also completely empty. No more ideas on how to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        @include('inc.navbar')   
        <div class = 'container'>
            <div class = 'row'>
                <div class = 'col-md-8 col-lg-8' >
                    @include('inc.messages')
                    @yeld('content')
                    <button class = 'btn' id = 'test1'>SES</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <footer id='footer' class = 'text-center'>
        <p>Copyright 2018 &copy; FitnessBook </p>
    </footer>

    @section('script')

    <script>
      $( "#test1" ).click(function(){
           alert( "Handler for .click() called.");
      });
    </script>

    @endsection

</html>
```

Comment: Try moving your script into the `<body>` and wrapping it in a document ready block: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is correctly addded? Can you open browser dev tools (F12) and in the console write: **jQuery.fn.jquery**. That gives you the jQuery versoin number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Removing @section('script') and adding the script src of cdn solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your `footer` tag and `script` inside `body` of HTML document.

and replace your script tag with below code :

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','#test1',function(){
  alert("Hello !!!");
});
<script>
```

Comment: replace <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script> with  <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>